# Port forwarding through shared internet connection

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, connection-sharing

I have shared my internet connection via Ethernet with another computer, using the shared option under Ethernet in Network settings. I believe this is working but I can't know for sure as I am unable to access Computer 2, because I don't have a monitor for it.

> Router ‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒> Computer 1 (Ubuntu) ‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒> Computer 2 (Other Linux)

So the first question is: how do I find out the IP of Computer 2 so I can SSH to it from Computer 1.

And: how can I forward a port right through from my router to the machine using the shared connection (computer 2).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question, use rinetd.

See this page for more details:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/rinetd-redirects-tcp-connections-from-one-ip-address-and-port-to-another.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nmap [image: Install nmap]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nmap) to scan the subnet to find Computer 2.

For example:

```
# nmap -T4 -F 10.42.0.*
```

will find the computers present 10.42.0.0 subnet. Some scripting can then be used to isolate the Ip found.

Still looking myself for your 2nd question ;)